# How to deal with loud (temporary) construction?

Tags: productivity

We work in an open office, we didn't have upper neighbours for a few months. They will come soon, as of this moment there are builders constructing their office, and they are loud!

I cannot tell them to quiet down, they have deadlines just as I do and, well, they are builders, I cannot tell them to hammer things with a cusion.
This is influenting my work flow. I cannot concentrate with the noise they are producing.

What steps can I take to concentrate with a noisy (temporary) environment?

Things I tried:

- headphones (not an option, I need to communicate with my co-workers)

Comment: What does your management say  about the issue, or are you the manager looking for a solution? The answer posted here might depend on that.

Comment: @MaskedMan Cannot do anything about it as it is temporary, Joe Not possible I need licensed software which is installed on a desktop.

Comment: @Ajaxkevi Is it possible to use (noise-cancelling)headphones, whilst everybody uses Skype, Lync, or any other professional communcation tool during this period? It's not ideal, but I think you're running out of options here.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you try headphones/hearing protection before discarding the idea. You can take them off when necessary, and if it's loud enough to be a problem health concerns trump convenience.

Comment: @keshlam I didn't discard the idea, it unfortunately just didn't work.

Comment: Did you try music headphones or hearing protection? Also note that at best these will reduce the noise; you'll still have to actively learn to accept and ignore the rest. I don't think you're going to find another answer that doesn't involve going elsewhere.  Time for a Spring vacation?

Comment: Would your employer let you work from home?

Comment: @Namfuak Not possible I need licensed software which is installed on a desktop.

Comment: @"I need licensed software which is installed on a desktop." Not that I advocate it in all cases, but this is one argument to be made for a Virtual Desktop (Though in the future - it's doubtable that you could implement it in a timely manner to resolve this issue).

Comment: @Zibbobz That is indeed planned. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Normal headphones don't help at all for blocking external noise. Some forms of earplug headphones do work, but most effective are earplugs. Take them out only long enough to communicate with your colleagues as needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What steps can I take to concentrate with a noisy (temporary) environment?

Some possibilities (in general, you've said some won't work for you specifically):

- Work from home (you can remote desktop into your machine)
- Everyone on your team get headsets with quality headphones and open a group chat instead of talking outloud (this is unlikely to be well received by everyone)
- Work different hours (if construction is 7-3, work 9-5 or 10-6)
- See if your team can relocate elsewhere temporarily
- Talk with your facilities people and determine if your companies lease says anything about this
- Headphones/earplugs
- Talk with the builders and determine their schedule and adjust your breaks/lunch accordingly (ie work when they are on lunch)
- Take time off (vacation, unpaid potentially)
- Relocate within your office (perhaps some areas are quieter?)

Unfortunately, there's not really a whole ton of good options.

---

HLGEM made a good point in a comment - you might take care to adjust any deadlines or future estimates you have based on the distractions and reduced productivity.

Comment: Since your office chose not to provide you a way to avoid this temporary distraction, I might also suggest that you amend deadlines and any time estimates you give to account for the reduced productivity.

Comment: @HLGEM great point, I added it to the answer